# Angular: How to access angular $scope.ng-model_name from outside $http.get method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs code for $http.get method, but when I tried to access $scope.metric.label. It is giving error like `"Error: $scope.metric is undefined` is not defined. I want to create the dynamic **url** from selection options. But I am not able to create dynamic url.

**DEMO** http://plnkr.co/edit/UrufgAUqjT8GOLz7QVsL?p=preview
In demo **uncomment alert(url)** you will see it is not working

```
//Fetching the metrics and filling the metric selection options
  $http.get("https:localhost:8080/metering/data/")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.metrics = response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters).concat(response.cinder_meters).concat(response.ipmi_meters).concat(response.neutron_meters).concat(response.swift_meters).concat(response.kwapi_meters);
      $scope.metric = $scope.metrics[0];
    });

  // Fetching the list of instances and filling the Group by selection options
  $http.get("https:localhost:8080/metering/project/")
    .success(function(response) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(response[0].instances));
      $scope.groups = response[0].instances;
      $scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0];     
    });

var url = "localhost?" + "meter=" + $scope.metric.label + "&group_by=project" ;
console.log(url);
```

I want to make selection option like following ...
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ceilometerCtrl">
    <select ng-model="metric" ng-options="value.label group by value.group for value in metrics" ng-change="update()">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="group_by" ng-options="value.Id for value in groups" ng-change="update()">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you define `$scope.metric` for the first time? It sounds like you're missing an initialization.

Comment: @Sosdoc It is define like `$scope.metric.label` in ulr, please check it, when it reaches $scope.metric, It gives error

Comment: If you're talking about `var url = ...` that's not a definition for `$scope.metric.label`, at that point your code doesn't have any value for `$scope.metric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your requests are **asynchronous**, you have to deal with callback to retrieve some data.

In angularJs, the **$http** return a **promise**, so you can combining them.

Also, you can use the **$q** service, with the **.all()** method. This method take an array of promises as parameter and return a promise that will be resolved when the promises in the parameter array will be resolved to.

[$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Furthermore, if you set properties of an object, like **$scope.metric**, you have to **declare it**, the object must be defined.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $http, $q) {

  //Declare metric
  $scope.metric = {};

  var defer = $q.defer();

  var url = '';

  //Declare promise
  var promise1 = $http.get("path_to_url");
  var promise2 = $http.get("another_path");

  //Declare our function callback to launch when promises are finished
  function callback(response){
    //response is an array of promises results, in the same order

    //reponse[0] is the promise1 result
    $scope.metric.name = response[0].data.name;

    //response[1] is the promise2 result
    $scope.group_by = response[1].data.group;

    url = "localhost?" + "meter=" + $scope.metric.name + "&group_by=" + $scope.group_by ;

    //Resolve data with the built url
    defer.resolve(url);
  }

  //When all promise are completed, then call callback function
  $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(callback);

  //Callback for our resolve result
  function print(url){
    console.log(url);
  }

  //Print data when the url is set
  defer.promise.then(print);


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering what are `response[0]` and `response[1]`

Comment: Here, `response` is an array of result of each promise which are passed into the array of .all() method. You'll get the result in the same order as you pass your parameters, so `response[0]` is the result for the `promise1`

Comment: Are response[0] and response[1] standards ?

Comment: in the callback function. For example, supposed `promise1` retrieve some metrics array object, you can do `$scope.metrics = response[0]`.

Moreover, you can access to them by `reponse[0].data.myField1`, `reponse[0].data.myField2`, etc ...

Comment: What do you mean by "standards" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85197/discussion-between-paul-boutes-and-neelabh-singh).

Comment: Thanks You save my day, but there is one problem that, In Metric options there is more than one json data, like `$scope.metrics = response[0].data.nova_meters;  $scope.metrics = response[0].data.glance_meters;` . How to add these two json reponse..

Comment: What is the format of your nova_meters, glance_meters, etc.. Array ?
For example if `response[0].data.nova_meters` is an array, you can push it into `$scope.metrics`. And do the same with your other data field.

Comment: Please see the Discussion Chat.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85197/discussion-between-paul-boutes-and-neelabh-singh

Comment: {serial: [data: {nova_list:[]  }, {glance_list []} ]

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `$scope.metric is undefined` because when you call

`var url = "localhost?" + "meter=" + $scope.metric.label + "&group_by=project";`

you're trying to access `label` on an object that **doesn't exist yet**.

The code inside a `.success` callback is executed **asynchronously** and you'll receive the results **only inside of its callback**. If you modify your code to access `$scope.metrics` inside of it you should be able to use it.

```
var url = "";

//Fetching the metrics and filling the metric selection options
$http.get("localhost/data/")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.metrics = response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters).concat(response.cinder_meters).concat(response.ipmi_meters).concat(response.neutron_meters).concat(response.swift_meters).concat(response.kwapi_meters);
      $scope.metric = $scope.metrics[0];

      // $scope.metric is available here, you can use it 
      url = "localhost?" + "meter=" + $scope.metric.label + "&group_by=project" ;
    });

  //$scope.metric isn't available here (http call hasn't finished yet)
  // will print undefined because it was never assigned to
  console.log($scope.metric);
```

Comment: Please see the DEMO, just uncomment alert(url), then it will not work http://plnkr.co/edit/UrufgAUqjT8GOLz7QVsL?p=preview

Comment: I got your point, But I will access the selection option outside, In My senario I have to make more than one selection option through $http.get..

Comment: @NeelabhSingh In your demo you're still modifying `url` before `$scope.metrics` is defined, what exactly do you need to do with the url?

Comment: yes because I need more than one selection option, After filling those selection option I will made url, But as you suggested I will be able to make only one selection option..

Comment: So, to make it clear, you want to send **multiple** http requests one after another? You make a new url at the end and want to call it again?

Comment: Yep.. It is like that, How I will made, Previously I made like your, But That time only one selection option was there Now here more than, please tell me how to do this..

Comment: in the `success` callback call `http.get` again with the new url, that's the only moment when your url is accessible.